# Using more than one event in the same element in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function, events

I'm trying to fire off a function when the user clicks a button AND/IF the user presses the enter key. I'm not sure how to store two event in the same element.

```
 <td> <input type= "button" disabled id ="e2" value="Exercise 2" onclick ="loadQsets(2);setRadioValues(2);disableInput() ;" /></td>
```

How do use both a onclick event and an enter key event in the same element to fire off the same function?

Comment: you can use onkeypress event of javascript

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the `keydown` event and put your logic there, under the `if statement`

See example. `13` is the key code for `Enter`

```js
document.getElementById('inp').addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
  if(e.keyCode === 13){
     console.log('Enter is pressed !');
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="inp">
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <td> <input type= "button" disabled id ="e2" value="Exercise 2" onclick ="loadQsets(2);setRadioValues(2);disableInput() ;" /></td>
```

```js
window.onload=function(){
  var btn = document.getElementById('e2');
  
  function handleStuff() {
    loadQsets(2); 
    setRadioValues(2);
    disableInput();
  }
  
  btn.onclick = function() { 
    handleStuff();
  };
  
  btn.onkeydown = function() {
    handleStuff();
  }
}
```

```html
 <td> <input type= "button" disabled id ="e2" value="Exercise 2" /></td>
```